# Hydrogen bond and van der Waals bond

Tags: forces

Just now I am studying about hydrogen bond and van der waals bond. I understand and able to differentiate between them but thinking of the similarities, do they have any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hydrogen is a special kind of intermolecular interactions that involve the electrostatic attraction between an electronegative atom, H which is bonded to N, O or F. Similarly, van der Waals force is a kind of intermolecular interactions between permanent dipoles or induced dipoles.

For example, the interactions between HCl is called van der Waals(permanent dipole interactions), whereas the interactions between HF is called hydrogen bonds.

Hydrogen bonds is much stronger than van der Waals forces, due to the fact that they hydrogen is bonded to a strongly electronegative atom, which increases the dipole moment.

[image][image]